# Characters Missing from Terminal/Libreoffice Sheet - Suspecting Virus

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, fonts

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Characters on my terminal goes missing, prompt becomes invisible, list of file is printed on right side without formatting.  In image below on cding into a folder the cursor moves to right and name of folder and prompt is invisible.

[image]

The problem is not limited to Teminal. All the character from Libreoffice sheets goes missing.

I did a virus scan yesterday with Calmav. It reported a virus like this

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome: Unix.Trojan.Mirai-5932143-0 FOUND
```

but a check on virustotal.com revel that it was a false positive.

What could the problem with the system?

---

According to @wjandrea the problem might be with graphic hardwar. I found graphic information using

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

*-display

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:28 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff iopor
```

Comment: This is a graphics issue, not a virus. I don't know much more than that, sorry, but it would be helpful if you post info about your graphics hardware.

Comment: @wjandrea Edited question providing information you asked for.

Comment: Same problem, 16.04 here.